# Why is Excel VBA rounding my integer division results?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA macro in Excel 2002 to manipulate date from a device that gives 10 values on each of 4 channels.

When I try to divide an integer by another integer to calculate the row and column, the result shows that it's using bankers rounding, as if it was a floating point variable.

```
Sub TestRounding()
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim Field As Integer
    Dim Channel As Integer

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    range("A1").Select

    For Field = 1 To 40
        Channel = (Field - 1) / 10
        Y = Field - 1
        ActiveSheet.range("A1").Offset(Y, Channel).Value = Field
    Next Field

End Sub
```

Y is the row to put the output in, which I usually set with

```
Y = (Field -1) mod 10
```

but I've left it as

```
Y = Field - 1
```

to illustrate the point more clearly in the resulting worksheet.

Channel is supposed to be the column that the output is put in.

When I run this macro, the values 1-6 get put in column A, then 7-15 get put into Column B, 16-26 get put into Column C, then 27-35 in Column D then 36-40 in Column E.

What I expected was that values 1-10 go into column A, 11-20 into column B, 21-30 into column C and 31-40 into column D.

I'm used to C and C++ where if I divide an integer by another integer, the result is calculated using integer maths. What's different in VBA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use "integer maths" for division use `\` instead of `/`.

> Integer Division \
>
> Dividing an item means cutting it in pieces or fractions of a set
>   value. Therefore, the division is used to get the fraction of one
>   number in terms of another. The Visual Basic language provides two
>   types of operations for the division. If you want the result of the
>   operation to be a natural number, called an integer, use the backlash
>   operator "\" as the divisor. The formula to use is:  `Value1 \ Value2`
>   This operation can be performed on two types of valid numbers, with or
>   without decimal parts. After the operation, the result would be a
>   natural number.
>
> `Decimal Division /`
>    The second type of division results in a decimal
>   number. It is performed with the forward slash "/". Its formula is: 
>   `Value1 / Value2`  After the operation is performed, the result is a
>   decimal number.

[Source](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson04.htm)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's sorted my problem. In over 25 years of programming (but as little Microsoft stuff as possible), this is the first time I think I've seen a backslash doing what I would normally expect a forward slash to do. NEver mind, I'll just have to check some other code that wasn't working properly as well, probably due to the same thing.

Comment: Nigel, if this sorted your problem, accept it as the answer to help others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: This is old, but I've run into an apparent problem.  I put `?5.5\2` in the immediate window, and it returns `3` rather than `2`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld 5.5/2 = 2.75 If you round that to an integer you get 3. I wouldn't consider that to be a problem. if you want it to round down, actually floor, use `int(5.5/2)`

Comment: @Daniel Integer division is defined elsewhere (including in VB, Wolfram) as division where the fractional part is **discarded**, not rounded. In addition, in VBA, it seems the operator is first rounding each value (using the round-to-even method of VBA), and then dividing the two values. For example 5.5\2.5 --> 3, but 5.5/2.5 --> 2.2

Comment: @Daniel I finally found some documentation for VBA's ``\`` operator that matches what I see happening (and is **different** from other implementations, where the result is truncated:  [Before division is performed, the numeric expressions are rounded to Byte, Integer, or Long expressions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/backslash-operator).

Answer (score 2):

The back slash is used for integer division, and the forward slash for decimal division. Change your forward slash to a back slash and you should get the result you are expecting.

http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson04.htm